# Comparison of exception message always fails in if my statement

Tags: java, exception

I have this variable in my Constants class:

```
public static final String EXCEPTION_STRING= "My Exceptions message";
```

I want to check for it in my catch and throw a particular message if it's found. This is what I came up with:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e.getMessage().equals(Constants.EXCEPTION_STRING)) {
        throw new ServiceException(MyClassName.class.toString(),
            Constants.EXCEPTION_STRING);
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Save failed: " + e);
    }
}
```

The `if` never seems to get entered even though I can see the correct exception message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are throwing the exception?

Comment: Debug it as you would any other string comparison failure. Print out both strings and see if the problem is obvous. Then print the length of both strings to see if one has a trailing space or denormalized character or similar. Finally compare character by character to pinpoint the problem, which could be a difference in capitalization, misspelling, punctuation, codepoint, or other things that are hard for humans to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Does your own custom exception get wrapped in another exception? In that case you need to do something like:

```
e.getCause().getMessage()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof AxisFault) {
        if (e.getMessage().equals(Constants.EXCEPTION_STRING)) {
            throw new ServiceException(MyClassName.class.toString(),
                Constants.EXCEPTION_STRING);
        }
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Save failed: " + e);
    }
}
```